# Complete file read at once using scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have to read a text file in Java, for that I am using below code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(
    ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("mock_test_data/MyFile.txt")));

scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
String content = scanner.next();
scanner.close();
```

As far as I know `String` has `MAX_LENGTH 2^31-1`

> But this code is reading only first 1024 characters from input
>   file(MyFile.txt).

I am not able to find the reason.

Comment: Few of might find this as duplicate question, but those questions don't give answer to my questions, the main reason is that I have to read complete file at once, without any loop.

Comment: It's an improper use of scanner, use a bytestream and read in a well sized buffer. It's not a good practice anyway to fetch a file in memory

Comment: I have tried that as well by FileInputStream, but in that FileInputStream is not able to read file for me.

Comment: What mean "not able to read file"? Post exceptions or code.

Comment: thanks for your help fantarama, I have found the answer for this. I have posted this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answers:

Finally I have found solution for this-

```
 String path = new File("src/mock_test_data/MyFile.txt").getAbsolutePath();
 File file = new File(path);
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
 byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
 fis.read(data);
 fis.close();
 content = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

As i have to read a very long file at once.

Answer (score 2):

I've read some of the comments and therefore I think it's necessary to point out that this answer does not care about good or bad practice. This is a stupid nice-to-know scanner trick for lazy people who need a quick solution.

```
final String res = "mock_test_data/MyFile.txt"; 

String content = new Scanner(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(res))
     .useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

Stolen from [here...](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/pat/archive/2004/10/stupid_scanner.html)

Comment: Could you please provide some better solution Which will take card about performance as well.

Comment: Your question does not mention any performance requirements at all. You wanted a solution which reads a file/stream completely... Here you go. I won't make any assumptions about performance as there are many factors which go way beyond some lines to read in a file. Besides, performance alone means nothing. There's also readability for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Example of using `BufferedReader`, works great for big files:

```
public String getFileStream(final String inputFile) {
        String result = "";
        Scanner s = null;

        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile)));
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                result = result + s.nextLine();
            }
        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
}
```

`FileInputStream` is used for smaller files.

Using `readAllBytes` and encoding them solves problem as well.

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
  throws IOException 
{
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
  return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file/326440#326440) question. It is very good.

Comment: @proudandhonour With BufferedReader you can read very large files, and the FileInputStream is for smaller ones.

Comment: thanks Aleksandar, by using your comment I have found the solution.

Comment: Answer didn't provide you a solution? Ok. Glad to help, even without vote :-)